# Delay the modal pop up in jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to delay jQuery modal `dialog` for 3 seconds. I tried by using delay but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what i tried:

```
$( ".modal-frequency" ).click(function() {
    var myGroupId = $(this).attr('data-id'); // data-id              
    $.post("sample.php",
    {
      name:myGroupId,
    }, 
    function(data,status) {
    $("#modal-frequency").load("frequency-modal.php").dialog({
      modal: true,
      minWidth: 700,
      minHeight: 200,
      dialogClass: "modal-dialog",
      show: "fadeIn",
         delay:3000
      });
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('bg-black opacity-60');
});
```

I am not able to find what is wrong here, or is there any alternative to this.

Comment: Have you tried using setTimeout() ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Use setTimeout() to delay**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    setTimeout(function(){

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 3000,
            },
        });

    }, 2000)
});
```

**Hope this helps..**